# visual memory improvement for mnemotecnics (method of loci)

Tags: cognitive-psychology, visualization, mnemonic

I have used the method of loci(art of memory/memory palace) in the past and I was able at the end to memorize a deck of shuffled 48 cards in 20 minutes but I had a very bland capacity for visualization which only improved a little thourgh my journey in mnemotecnics
I read in a book by a ucl alumni Frances Yates that professionals in the method of loci, just imagine vivid life like scenes in a place to memorize text they just put the text as it is they just imagine the text/page/book like it was in their hands in this imaginary place and this is how they memorize it.

So I am looking for visualition exercice specific to the method of loci to improve my visual memory or capacity to visualize.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome! This seems like a a nice focused question. While you await an answer, some things you can still improve: make sure to use punctuation so this is easier to read, and add a reference to the specific book you used to learn what you did so far.